# Вычислить выражение, записанное в String

Tags: java, jframe

Писал я графический калькулятор и пришла идея записать все выражение в `String`, то есть пользователь набирает кнопками, то что ему нужно решить, к примеру 2313 + 3435 - 53 * 2 и оно все пишется в `String text`. Есть ли библиотеки которые могут это реализовать, или предложение как это можно сделать?

Как записать в `String` я знаю, главное это - как решить это уравнение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java

Comment: [Почитайте про Reverse Polish Notation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120451/reverse-polish-notation-calculator-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я офигел, когда впервые увидел, что Java умеет в JavaScript)

```
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String expression = "6*3+8/2-2.3";

    try {
        float result = Float.valueOf(engine.eval(expression).toString());
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStatckTrace();
    }
```